# Creating an invoice line using Odoo (OpenERP) WebService API for PHP

Tags: php, odoo

I'm trying to create an invoice line using next code:

```
    // Invoice line creation
    $result = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
        'account.invoice.line', 'create',
        array(array(
            'Invoice'=>$invoice, 
            'invoice_id'=>$invoice_id,
            'product_id'=>$product_id,
            'quantity'=>$product_quantity,
            'name'=>$product_name,
            'price_unit'=>$product_price,
            'invoice_line_tax_id'=>array($odoo_tax_id)
        )));
```

The register is created within invoice, but it hasn't any tax.

UPDATE

The product used for the invoice line was created before using:

```
        // Product creation
        $product_id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
            'product.product', 'create',
            array(array(
                'default_code'=>$product_ref,
                'name'=>$product_name,
                'list_price'=>$product_price,
            ))
        );
```

And the invoice was created using:

```
    // Invoice creation
$invoice_id = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
    'account.invoice', 'create',
    array(array('partner_id'=>$parter_id,'account_id'=>$odoo_invoice_account_id)));

$invoice = $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,
    'account.invoice', 'read', array($invoice_id),
    array());
```

UPDATE

Following the answer given by Christophe Combelles, I ended with this code:

```
'invoice_line_tax_id'=>array(array(4, $tax_id,false))
```

Other array is necessary because this format is a list of triplets.

Comment: Does your product have taxes enabled?

Comment: I updated the post with the product that is used for the invoice line and I didn't setup any tax, however when I use the product to create an invoice within Odoo hasn't any problem using that product

Answer (score 2):

For your `invoice_line_tax_id` field, try to replace `array($odoo_tax_id)` with `array(6, 0, array($odoo_tax_id))`

Not sure about the php syntax, in python it would be `(6, 0, [tax_id])`

This is documented in https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.models.Model.write

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finally I ended with 'invoice_line_tax_id'=>array(array(4, $tax_id,false))

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the account.tax module?
https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/7.0/account_tax_invoice/

> You can assign multiple taxes to a Product. Assuming you have set up
>   the appropriate taxes, you would use the menu Sales ‣ Products ‣
>   Products to open and edit a Product definition, then:
>
> select one or more Sale Taxes for any products that you might sell,
>   which may include a Sales Tax or Output VAT and a Sales Eco Tax ,
>
> select one or more Purchase Taxes for any products that you might
>   purchase, which may include a Purchase Tax or Input VAT and a Purchase
>   Eco Tax .
>
> Generally, when you make a purchase or sales, the taxes assigned to
>   the product are used to calculate the taxes owing or owed.

More info on how odoo handles Taxes at https://doc.odoo.com/6.1/book/3/3_9/tax_structure/